# Android SetImageResource failed to work in Gridview on button click

Tags: android, android-gridview

I try to display some items in a Gridview and set button click listener. When the item was clicked, it shows a dialog box, **if clicking yes, it will change the Imageview.**

**java coding**

```
public class table extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

GridView gridView;
my_adapter my_adapter;
String table_names[]={"1a","1b","1c","1d","2a","2b","2c","2d","3a","3b","3c","3d"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

    gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    my_adapter=new my_adapter(this,table_names);
    gridView.setAdapter(my_adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, long l) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Table number: "+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString())
            .setMessage("Open Table？")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    my_adapter.change_img(); // change to new image

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    my_adapter.change_img2(); // change back to original image
                }
            })
            .show();
}
}

class my_adapter extends BaseAdapter{

ImageView imageView;
LayoutInflater inflater=null;
Context ctx;
String table_names[];
ArrayList store_table_no;

my_adapter(Context ctx, String table_names[]){
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.table_names=table_names;
    store_table_no=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<table_names.length;i++){
        store_table_no.add(table_names[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return store_table_no.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return store_table_no.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row=view;

    if(row==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single,null);
    }

    TextView tv_table_no=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.table_no);
    imageView=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tv_table_no.setText(""+store_table_no.get(i));

    return row;
}

public void change_img(){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.table_full);
}

public void change_img2(){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.table3d2);
}
}
```

**single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="101"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/table_no"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/table"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot, please have a look

[image]

It simply doesn't change the imageview. Looks like something is wrong with my coding. anyone knows what's happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing GridView's OnItemClickListener to show a dialog and getting decision from user for each item. When you are showing up a dialog it needs to update current clicked item of grid. But in your case you have change_img() in adapter. No position specification is given to the adapter.

To make it work, move your logic from activity to adapter. Handle the click events with the positions.

In your activity,

```
public class table extends AppCompatActivity{

GridView gridView;
my_adapter my_adapter;
String table_names[] = {"1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "3a", "3b", "3c", "3d"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    my_adapter = new my_adapter(this, table_names);
    gridView.setAdapter(my_adapter);
}


class my_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context ctx;
    String table_names[];
    ArrayList<String> store_table_no;

    my_adapter(Context ctx, String table_names[]) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.table_names = table_names;
        store_table_no = new ArrayList<>();
        store_table_no.addAll(Arrays.asList(table_names));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return store_table_no.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return store_table_no.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;

        if (row == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single, null);
        }

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        TextView tv_table_no = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.table_no);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tv_table_no.setText(store_table_no.get(i));


        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(GridActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Table number: " + store_table_no.get(i))
                        .setMessage("Open Table？")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        });
        return row;
    }

}
}
```

In your xml file add id to Parent RElative Layout as follows,

**single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="101"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/table_no"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/table"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thx. but quite a number of errors. plz check your coding. have u test the coding?

Comment: Plz take note When clicking on the item, The table no. will be shown in the Dialog.

Comment: I have edited. I've checked this time. It's working. No errors and all.